# C : How to load, store, and print a mixed matrix of character strings and integer numbers

Tags: c, string, matrix, character

I have been trying to solve a problem for over a year now and just don’t seem to posses the skills yet to solve it so I was hoping  maybe someone could help me? I am new to stack overflow and definitely a rookie programmer. I am using Codelite as a program to write and compile code.

In C I would like to load, save, and print a matrix into the terminal/screen, but not just a matrix of numbers but a matrix of both character strings AND numbers. If this isn’t possible, is it possible to load in values from a text file (tab delimited (.txt) or comma separated list (.csv)) list that contains both names and numbers in it by loading the values into separate matrices?

[image: Here is a sample of a matrix that I would like to load into the C program (image)]

[image: This is a sample of the code that I have so far (image)]

Comment: Please don't post images of code.  Use the code formatting option to post the code directly into your question.  You should also add the sample data into the question, rather than posting an image of that.

Comment: One way to do this is to build the table in a 2D text buffer, finally outputting it to the terminal. Some advantages are that you don't have to process items in sequence, or mess with the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to wrap your head around what you are trying to do, you have to understand what tools C provides to help you coordinate differing types of data as a single unit. C provides a structure (or struct). Any time you think about having to manage say, character data, and numeric data while preserving the relationship between the different types -- think struct.

Here, given the data you show and the fact that you have attempting `int column=4;`, it appears you have a `firstname`, `lastname`, `some_ID`, and `some_num` associated with each record of data. That would lend directly to a struct containing two character arrays and two numeric values. (for example purposes, we will simply used fixed size arrays with automatic storage to store the names -- but you are free to simply declare pointers and allocate for each name if you like).

To begin, let's `#define` the constants we will need to use, so we are not using *magic-numbers* in our code (but note, `scanf` *field-width* modifiers cannot be variables, so that is an exception):

```
/* if you need a constant #define one (or more) */
#define MAXPPL   16     /* max people (e.g. number of elements in array) */
#define MAXNM    64     /* max name length for both first, last */
#define MAXC   1024     /* max characters for read buffer (per-line) */
```

(don't skimp on buffer size, if your names can get close to 64 chars, then double the size)

Now let's define our struct, using a `typedef` as a convenience wo we can use `person_t` as the type and don't have to type `struct person` everywhere the type is needed, e.g.

```
typedef struct person { /* use a struct to coordinate differing types */
    char first[MAXNM],
         last[MAXNM];
    unsigned id,
             num;
} person_t;
```

Now we have a structure that can hold the `first` and `last` names (63-chars + *nul-terminating char* each) and two `unsigned` values, what I call the `id` and `num` (for lack of better words). Likewise, verify `unsigned` will work for the numeric type. A 4-byte `unsigned` can handle values from `0  to  4294967295`, choose a new type if needed, e.g. `long long unsigned` or use the exact width `uint64_t` provided in `stdint.h`

With that, the rest of your challenge is straight forward. You declare an array of `person_t` (an array of your struct), read each line of data into a buffer of `MAXC` size (which should be more than sufficient, but validate anyway, by checking the `strlen()` of the buffer after each read and insuring it is less than `MAXC-1` chars and the last character is `'\n'`), and parse each line into a `first`, `last`, `id`, and `num`, storing the parsed values in your array, while insuring you do not attempt to store more names and numbers in your array than you declared.

For example, to fill up to `MAXPPL` elements of your array while reading each line of data, you could do something like the following:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";                            /* read buffer  */
    unsigned n = 0;                                 /* person count */
    person_t people[MAXPPL] = {{ .first = "" }};    /* array of people */

    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* fill up to MAXPPL struct while reading each line of data */
    while (n < MAXPPL && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        /* temp struct to hold parsed values */
        person_t tmp = { .first = "" };

        /* validate entire line read here - left to you */
```

Above, note that `n` is simply a record counter you will increment each time you add a `first`, `last`, `id`, and `num` element to your array, so only attempting to read while `n < MAXPPL` protects you from attempting to store more elements than you have space for. Including the return of `fgets` in your condition guarantees you will only attempt to parse values from the `buf` if `buf` has been filled and contains valid characters to parse.

That brings us to the parsing point. You have read your line into `buf` and have validated `buf` contains characters, but how to split the line into pieces so you have your `first`, `last`, `id`, and `num` values stored within each struct element? There are a number of ways to do that, you can use a pair of pointers and just walk down the buffer checking for the delimiter, you can call `strtok` with the proper delimiter (or use `strsep` if there is the possibility of an empty field in a csv file), or, and probably the simplest here is just to use `sscanf` to split `buf` into `first`, `last`, `id`, and `num` and then validate the return (that 4-converstions took place)

You also mentioned the potential to have either a *comma separated values* file or a *tab-delimited* file, which you can handle with a simple `if ... else if ....` where you check for *comma separated values*, first and then *whitespace* separated value next (or vice versa -- your choice), e.g.

```
        /* attempt comma separated parse */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%63[^,],%63[^,],%u,%u", 
                    tmp.first, tmp.last, &tmp.id, &tmp.num) == 4)
            people[n++] = tmp;
        /* attempt space/tab separated parse */
        else if (sscanf (buf, "%63s %63s %u %u",
                    tmp.first, tmp.last, &tmp.id, &tmp.num) == 4)
            people[n++] = tmp;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */
```

(**note:** the use of differing *conversion-specifiers* between the two `sscanf` calls -- make sure you understand why, see [scanf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html))

At that point, you have all your data read into your array of struct, and you are free to do with it what you need. The number of elements filled with data is stored in `n`. So you can simply output your data in your "matrix" form using a simple `for` loop, e.g.

```
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++)    /* output results */
        printf ("%-10s %-10s %10u %10u\n", people[i].first, people[i].last,
                people[i].id, people[i].num);
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* if you need a constant #define one (or more) */
#define MAXPPL   16     /* max people (e.g. number of elements in array) */
#define MAXNM    64     /* max name length for both first, last */
#define MAXC   1024     /* max characters for read buffer (per-line) */

typedef struct person { /* use a struct to coordinate differing types */
    char first[MAXNM],
         last[MAXNM];
    unsigned id,
             num;
} person_t;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";                            /* read buffer  */
    unsigned n = 0;                                 /* person count */
    person_t people[MAXPPL] = {{ .first = "" }};    /* array of people */

    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* fill up to MAXPPL struct while reading each line of data */
    while (n < MAXPPL && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        /* temp struct to hold parsed values */
        person_t tmp = { .first = "" };

        /* validate entire line read here - left to you */

        /* attempt comma separated parse */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%63[^,],%63[^,],%u,%u", 
                    tmp.first, tmp.last, &tmp.id, &tmp.num) == 4)
            people[n++] = tmp;
        /* attempt space/tab separated parse */
        else if (sscanf (buf, "%63s %63s %u %u",
                    tmp.first, tmp.last, &tmp.id, &tmp.num) == 4)
            people[n++] = tmp;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++)    /* output results */
        printf ("%-10s %-10s %10u %10u\n", people[i].first, people[i].last,
                people[i].id, people[i].num);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input Files**

Comma Separated

```
$ cat dat/namesnumbers.txt
John,Smith,135897,587555
Kelly,Johnson,46359,7811
Sam,Samson,78555279,4525
Thomas,Jefferson,765,31
```

Tab Separated

```
$ cat dat/namesnumberstab.txt
John    Smith   135897  587555
Kelly   Johnson 46359   7811
Sam     Samson  78555279        4525
Thomas  Jefferson       765     31
```

**Example Use/Output**

Output is the same regardless of input file.

```
$ ./bin/namesnumbers dat/namesnumbers.txt
John       Smith          135897     587555
Kelly      Johnson         46359       7811
Sam        Samson       78555279       4525
Thomas     Jefferson         765         31
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I have read and re-read this comment a few times over the past few days and have realized that one, I am in way over my head for my current skill level, and two, I have so, so very much to learn. I can't thank you enough for your extremely in depth answer to my question! I think that for the short term I am going to reach out to others to help write this code with me, but long term I will continue to try to learn more about coding so that I can truly grasp all of the information that you have relayed to me. Again, thank you very much for your answer and for your time!

Comment: Don't sweat it. Learning C is a journey, not something you do in some fixed amount of time. In fact, you never really ever get done learning C, they have a way of changing the standard every decade or so `:)`. You learn to program the same way your eat a whale --- *one byte at a time*...

Comment: As I read your question, your main stumbling block was "I have this character data and I have these values, they all relate to each other, but how do I consider them all as one chunk of data?" That is what a `struct` provides in C. Just like you can have an *array-of-int* or an *array-of-characters*, you can also have an *array-of-struct*. That lets you put different data together (your names and ID's) into a single chunk (a `stuct` or structure), and then you can have an array of those chunks. Start with a simple one `struct simple { int a; char b; };` You put an `int` and `char` together!

Comment: A good bit of background [struct (C programming language - Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language))

Answer (score -2):

I propose to apply the concept described here, it is a helpful article for reaching your final goal:
https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

In your case I would apply that concept this way:

- make a program which can read in one of the two kinds of input,
  either number or string, choose the easier one
- then change to loading the other kind, the harder one;
  I assume that loading strings is harder, but it is your opinion that counts
- then upgrade to loading the easier one from a simple list in a file,
  i.e. 1D
- then switch to loading the harder one, still 1D
- then upgrade to loading easier one 2D, but only one kind, always the same
- then switch to loading harder one 2D, still only one kind, always the same
- Now you can load both versions. Analyse your input. Can you always predict which kind you will have ot read next? Looking at your example it seems so, alway two srings, two numbers.
- If you can always predict the kind to load next, then mix the two versions of your 2D loading code and make sure that the code always reads in the correct kind next.

Here are some additional hints, which seem to be relevant for you (as implied by the code you have shown):

Make sure that you read strings into large enough buffers. This has only single-char buffers in each cell of the 2D matrix:

```
char t[r][c];
```

You wisely avoid `scanf()`, that is good. However even with fsanf(), you need to take more care. Always check the return value, it tells you how far the scanning got. If it did not succeed, make sure you can handle the problem.

Here is a helpful article on scanning, by trying to convince you not to use scanf(), it actually teaches extremely helpful lessongs on how to use it. It also recommends alternatives. The most important one being to read whole lines and parse them as a big string.

http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Let me know if you can NOT predict the next kind of input. It will be much tougher, but maybe I can still recommend something. Do tell more details on how it can vary and give more examples, which are of a different pattern, to demonstrate the variety of your input.